# Using global variables inside template includes

Tags: php, twig

I need to use a global defined variable, $LANG, inside an include so that I can select the good file according to the user language.

My variable is defined like this :

```
// File : index.php
// Twig is defined earlier
$twig->addGlobal('lang', $LANG);

// File : body.html
<div id="svg">
    {% include 'svg/mysvg-'.lang.'.svg' %}
</div>
```

Can I use the variable as I tried to use it in the include? It doesn't work like this.

Comment: You added the global `lang` to twig, but in the template you're trying to access it with `LANG`!?

Comment: Edited, mistake sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just be able to do it the way you did it in your question. But concatenating strings in Twig is not with `.` byt with `~`.

```
{% include 'svg/mysvg-' ~ lang ~ '.svg' %}
```

Comment: Thanks, better and cleaner way than my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it :

```
{% include  (lang == 'fr') ? 'svg/mysvg-fr.svg' : 'svg/mysvg-de.svg' %}
```

via : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html